# Can we hide ID and its value from Query string in php?

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I am facing problem with Query String in one of my Joomla Project.

I have video section in my project and also showing top video on home page. so when I link to detail page I am passing id of video. but here my client does not want to show id in string and its also cause some security problem.

So is there any solution to hide that ID from Query string?

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things to make this work as your client want.

- Encrypt the link data and send. At the PHP end decry-pt and use them.
- When user click on the link user use a form submission. Pass the value as hidden fields. Using POST method is secure than the GET method. Here also you can encrypt the values you send.

Comment: Hi Dasun, Thanks, I like you second option but a bit problem that I have put top video slider and I linked that each video with <a> tag.So How can I pass it ?

Comment: if I understand you correctly you could use a onclick function on the link to get this done.